# Add an Excel file as a linked server in SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, microsoft-excel

I'm trying to add a linked server to an Excel 2010 file from SQL Server 2012. Every reference I've found online for doing this is using older versions of SQL Server, and the driver that they tell you to use 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', is not present in 2012 from what I can tell.

Can anyone tell me which provider I need to use and what the product name, data source, and provider string should be?

For reference, this is the screen I'm looking at:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you are running the 64-bit edition of SQL Server but only have the 32-bit Jet provider installed.  If this is the case you will need to remove the 32-bit provider and install the 64-bit provider.  The Access Database Engine will install the Jet provider which is the same provider used to connect to Excel.

[**Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the driver *Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0* according to this guide, http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

The driver is a part of the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) that @squillman already linked.